# Import existing project into eclipse, it auto combine old version with the new one

Tags: java, eclipse, git, grails, ggts

I want to import project A to eclipse(GGTS),but I already have A which is an old version but of same name. When I use import existing project, it automatically combine two version together but I don't want this happen.
I also use git so I'm not sure what make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=40493

But you can try to change the name tag in the .project file in the project before importing it.